# What is the closest OneNote Linux alternative?

Tags: linux, microsoft-onenote

As in topic; I would especially appreciate notes import from OneNote, some notes sync option and gtk base.
Or maybe it is not an overkill to run OneNote on Wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this answer is not what you would like to hear but: there is no alternative to OneNote under Linux. There are some GNU programs which try to provide a similar functionality but they are all too unreliable or lack functionality.

Comment: Agree; in fact I have moved to a bunch of text files supervised and synced via Git. And I don't miss OneNote.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use the [OneNote Web App](https://onenote.com/).  You just need a Windows Live ID.  If the [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) plugin works with it, it will enhance the interface.

The OneNote Web App obviously does not have all the features of the desktop version, but it is still useful for keeping basic notes.

Comment: This seems quite good, despite I'm still afraid that it will somehow activate Live Messenger (-; Seriously,I'll wait for some more answers but this seems the best option.

Comment: @mbq:  If you already have a lot of OneNote notebooks, just move them to SkyDrive.  When you open them up from there they will open in the OneNote Web App.  You can open the same notebooks in OneNote 2010 directly from SkyDrive.

Answer (score 3):

You could try Evernote. It has no official Linux client, but there are unofficial versions like [Everpad](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad).

Comment: Care to explain why you think Evernote would be a good replacement?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend: [BasKet Note Pads](http://basket.kde.org/) for KDE.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "notes import", what is your goal?  Do you print these notes on paper, save them digitally, or alter existing PDFs?

As far as notetaking is concerned, I really enjoy [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) for taking notes and annotating PDFs in Linux.

Here are some more OneNote alternatives from [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/SearchResult.aspx?profile=all&search=onenote&category=software).

Comment: Import my quite huge OneNote database to the new tool.

Comment: Importing existing OneNote files might be difficult.  Microsoft is notoriously bad at providing information about file formats to facilitate conversions to other formats.